# C# code to get data from Endpoint with username and private key

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have this endpoint which i want to get data from . This endpoint has certain method to get data and  post data . Now what happens is i have the username and private key when i need to get data from the endpoint i will need this to be posted so that it return a url with hash id on it when i can run it on the browser to see the data returned . Below is an example of that url:

https://endpoint/api/product/associatedproducst?username=myusername&version=2&hash=69865ce2329d1d0904498f64d94e8392
Below is the code i have :

```
 public string Getproduct(string endpoint, string username, string privatekey)
        {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://endpoint");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("username:" + username);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("privatekey:" + privatekey);

        //pass basic authentication credentials
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuserid", "myid");

        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
            }

        }
```

I need some help and guidance on how i can continue from the code above so that i can generate those url and hash id on it so that i can read the data and display it as well .

Please note this endpoint has methods to get certain data how can i call those methods so that correct url can return from it to get data.

Comment: API key != private key; please avoid using them interchangeably. (If you are expected to send a private key to a remote system, that system is extremely poorly designed). I'd recommend cleaning up your question to make it a bit more clear exactly what you're asking. It will also be difficult to say whether or not you're adding your headers correctly without knowing the type of system you're attempting to connect to and seeing its documentation. Different systems use different authentication standards.

Comment: @esqew i am trying to get data from this website api  https://api.mrandmrssmith.com/as/rest/documentation#response-formats and o their test zone https://api.mrandmrssmith.com/as/rest/testzone .  I am new to this kind of api integration . Can you guide me on the best way to get and post data to this api . See i have to post the private key and user name to the endpoint and call the method which will return the url with the hash id which i can run to see the data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an HttpClient.  I looked at the API and came up with the solution.  The API mentions that you should never send the private key.  The private key is used to generate the HASH you are sending through the query string. For the private function below I am just guessing your use case.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;



var client = new HttpClient();
        public async string Getproduct(string endpoint, string username, string privateKey)
        {
            var queryString = string.Format("?username={0}&version=2", username).ToUpper();
            var hash = GenerateHash(privateKey, queryString);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

           var url = string.Format("{0}{1}&hash={2}",endpoint, queryString, hash);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return json;
                }
                else
                {
                    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    //handle code here.
                }
            }

        }
        public async void PostProduct(string endpoint, string username, string privateKey)
        {
            var queryString = string.Format("?username={0}&version=2", username).ToUpper();
            var hash = GenerateHash(privateKey, queryString);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}&hash={2}", endpoint, queryString, hash);
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("hotel_id ", "1");
            dict.Add("room_id ", "2");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    //handle code here.
                }
            }
        }
        private string GenerateHash(string privateKey, string queryString)
        {
            var md5 = MD5.Create();
            string salt = queryString;
            byte[] bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + privateKey));
            return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
        }
```

Comment: thanks it really helped me in the right direction can i have your email i may have a project for you